# How can I replace text dynamically time after time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to replace the content of a paragraph using items from an array dynamically time after time. The output is fine when I use `console.log()` to check the results. But it is not replacing the content on the paragraph as expected, just shows the last word when the iteration is complete.

Here is the code I made to create and iterate over the array:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var _strng = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet";
    var _array = new Array();
    _array = _strng.split(' ');

    jQuery.each(_array, function(index,item)
    {
        console.log(item); // Works fine
        $('p').html(item); // Only shows the last word when the iteration is over
        wait(1000); // Custom function
        console.clear();
    });
});
```

The **wait()** function:

```
function wait(_timeframe)
{
    var final = 0;
    var timeframe = new Date(_timeframe);    
    var initial = Date.now();
    final = initial + _timeframe;

    while (Date.now() < final) { };
}
```

**HTML** code:

```
<p>Text to be replaced here</p>
```

Comment: Because that's what `html()` does.  It replaces content

Comment: There exists `setInterval()` and `setTimeout()` functions on Javascript for your purposes, avoid using a custom wait. Here is a good tutorial for you: [Timing On JS](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp)

Comment: Your `wait` function blocks the ui.. use `window.setTimeout`

Comment: i think you are trying to append, not replace all the p tags with all elements (the last will be final as there are no more itterations

Comment: Show us the `wait()` function, please. I suspect it makes use of `setTimeout()` which is delayed execution, so really everything would just happen at once in the future.

Answer (score 9):

You can use [setInterval()](https://javascript.info/settimeout-setinterval#setinterval) method for this approach. On the next example, we use it to replace the text of the `<p>` element every `N` seconds, looping back to the start of the array when it reach the end.

Also, there is a `button` to show how to stop the execution of this procedure using the [clearInterval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearInterval) method (just in case you need to learn about it).

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var _str = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet";
    var _array = _str.split(' ');
    var _idx = 0;

    // Define the time interval between executions (in milliseconds).

    var _ivalTime = 3000;

    // Define the method that will change the text.

    var changeText = function()
    {
        var item = _array[_idx++];
        console.log(item);
        $('p').html(item);

        // Check the restart (loop back) condition.

        _idx = (_idx >= _array.length) ? 0 : _idx;
    };

    // Start the procedure to change text.

    var ival = setInterval(changeText, _ivalTime);

    // Register listener on the click event of stop button.
    
    $("#btnStop").click(function()
    {
        clearInterval(ival);
    });
});
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:50% !important;}
.as-console {background-color:black !important;color:lime;}

p {
  background: skyblue;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>INITIAL TEXT...</p>
<br>
<button id="btnStop" type="button">Stop</button>
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem is, that you wait functions blocks the ui. Instead, you should use `window.setTimeout`, which calls a callback after a specific time.

You could try something like this for your problem

```
$(function() {
    var words = ["Lorem", "ipsum", "dolor"];
    var $element = $("p");

    // callback function
    var f = function() {
        $element.html(words.shift());
        if (words.length > 0) {
            window.setTimeout(f, 1000);
        }
    }

    // initial call
    f();
};
```